# Data sets from motion capture?

Tags: data-request, computing

Wondering if there are any datasets of motion capture data from people or animals running, walking, manipulating objects etc. Could be quite useful for robotic training, etc!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a source of many varied subjects, motions, and motion categories: [CMU Graphics Lab Motion Capture Database](http://mocap.cs.cmu.edu/)

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking for data on motion capture in order to test parsing algorithms, the C3D Standard has many examples of mocap data available here: https://www.c3d.org/sampledata.html

Answer (score 2):

The UCI Human Activity Recognition Using Smartphones Data Set is available here:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones

This is motion data assoiciated with humans performing specific activities captured via the sensors on smartphones.

Might be what you're looking for.